# Convergence of time translated iid process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Asume we have a sequence of i.i.d. rv $(Y_n)_{n\geq 0}$, with finite expectation. 
If $\sqrt{n}^{-1}Y_n\rightarrow 0$ almost sureley, can one conclude, that 
$\sqrt{n}^{-1}Y_{n+m}\rightarrow 0$ almost sureley for an $m\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The question is odd since the sequences $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ and $(Y_{n+m})_{n\geqslant0}$ are equally distributed hence one knows a priori that every event $$A_m=[\sqrt{n}^{-1}Y_{n+m}\to0]$$ has the same probability. In particular, if $P(A_0)=1$ (your hypothesis) then $P(A_m)=1$ for every $m$. This shows that the result is much more general than the answer below seems to indicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If $c_nY_n(\omega)\to0$ and $\frac{c_n}{c_{n+m}}\to c\in\mathbb R$ then $$c_nY_{n+m}(\omega)=\frac{c_n}{c_{n+m}}c_{n+m}Y_{n+m}(\omega)\to c\times0=0$$

Comment: Thanks, with $c_n:=\sqrt{n}^{-1}$ and $c_{n+m}=\sqrt{n+m}^{-1}$ we conclude that $\sqrt{n}^{-1}Y_{n+m}\rightarrow 0$ almost sureley.

Comment: That is correct.